# Hilbert space continuous linear map, one dimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Could you help me with the following exercise?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $\alpha : H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a linear continuous mapping, $\alpha \neq 0$. Prove that the orthogonal complement $(ker)^{\perp}$ is a one dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Since $H$ is a Hilbert space, and $\alpha$ a continuous linear functional, we know that there exists a vector $h \in H$ such that for all $x \in H$, $\alpha(x)=<x,h>$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: On the other hand, the item in the question could be a step in the proof of your answer.

Comment: $x \in ker \alpha \iff \alpha (x)=0 \iff <x,h>=0$ for a certain vector $h \in H$ $\iff h \in (ker \alpha)^{\perp}$

Comment: On second thought, I don't think it's a good approach. Can we deduce $(ker \alpha) ^{\perp}$ 's dimension?

Comment: Note that $x$ is in $ker(\alpha)$ if and only if $x$ is orthogonal to $h$. So, $ker(\alpha)^{\perp}$ is 1 -dimensional.

Comment: Maybe it's because it's late, but I still don't see how the fact that $x \in ker \alpha \iff <x,h>=0$ imples that the orthogonal complement of $ker \alpha$ is one-dimensional. Could you be a bit more explicit? Or is it really so obvious?

Comment: $ker(\alpha)=<h>^\perp$, where $<h>$ is the 1-diml subspace spanned by $h$. Then $ker(\alpha)^\perp=<h>^{\perp \perp}=<h>$, as $<h>$ is a closed subspace. Hope this helps.